# .Net Mailkit Pop3 Connection with Proxy Settings

Tags: .net, proxy, pop3, mailkit, mimekit

I am trying to connect Pop3 client using given proxy settings. However, I got "Authentication failed" error. When i try it with imap which is with port 993, It works just fine. I cant understand why it does not work for Pop3 protocol. Is there any way that I could solve this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

```
 ProxySettings ProxySetting = new ProxySettings
                {
                    Name = "asaf",
                    Host = "192.168.3.55",
                    Port = 808,
                    Auth = new Authorization
                    {
                        Type = AuthenticationMethodConstants.Ntlm,
                        User = "User-001",
                        Password = "Deneme123"
                    }

        };
        using (var client = new Pop3Client())
        {
            client.Timeout = 120000;
            if (ProxySetting != null)
            {
                client.ProxyClient = ProxySetting.CreateHttpProxyClient();
                Console.WriteLine("Current proxy: " + client.ProxyClient.ProxyHost + ":" + client.ProxyClient.ProxyPort);
            }
            
            client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;
           
            client.Connect("outlook.office365.com", 995, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);

            client.Authenticate("mcs234@lenfs.onmicrosoft.com", "phtfg456!");
```

Comment: It looks like you've implemented your own custom proxy client (ProxySettings is not part of MailKit). The problem is likely in that code somewhere. If ProxySettings.CreateHttpProxyClient() is instantiating MailKit's HttpProxyClient, bear in mind that MailKit's HttpProxyClient implementation only supports Basic authorization, not NTLM.

Comment: I changed it to Basic authorization and still got the same authentication failed error. Inside the CreateHttpProxyClient() method, I use MailKit's HttpProxyClient method that checks user credentials and returns new HttpProxyClient(Host, Port, networkCredential). Do you have any suggestion to solve this?